# Phantom: Create custom index and queries?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I'm using Cassandra and [Phantom](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom) as Scala DSL and driver.

Now, I would like to use [Cassandra Lucene Index](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index) as Cassandra plugin. They provide a Lucene-based secondary index that can be created this way:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX tweets_index ON tweets ()
USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
WITH OPTIONS = {
   'refresh_seconds': '1',
   'schema': '{
      fields: {
         id: {type: "integer"},
         user: {type: "string"},
         body: {type: "text", analyzer: "english"}
      }
   }'
};
```

Unfortunately, I've not found a way yet to create such an index using Phantom as DSL. So I'd like to ask here if it's possible at all using Phantom or if I have to use raw CQL statements or the Java API for Cassandra?

Also I guess it's not possible to use Phantom for querying the Lucene index?

Comment: Hi @Aliquis, this is possible, however only in the subscription version of phantom. Happy to help you with that, but this is not the right place. Get in touch with us via my profile.